# How to find server's highest and lowest load time frame

Tags: ubuntu, performance

I want to know at what time a server relaxes most. I need the most idle time frame of the server, the lowest one.

The goal is to perform some data analysis task without hurting server response at peak time.

So, if I find that a server handles very few requests between 00:00 to 03:00. Then I can schedule a task to cook on data collected or take backup.

I tried googling but didn't found any answer for my question. I tried other commands such as `top`, `w`, `uptime`, `vmstat`, etc.

Does a Linux server store average load log to somewhere, so that I can find the lowest one?

Comment: Suggest you look into sysstat, which by default gathers performance stats every few minutes and usually stores in location such `/var/log/sa`.

Answer (score 3):

You can monitor the server load using `nmon` analyzer. Following things you can monitor and also you can schedule the `cron` for a specific time and analyze the load.

- Disk
- CPU
- Memory Stats
- DISK I/O
- NFS Information

Example:

Collect the 12 hours data. `-f` will take default hostname for the file or you can also use `-F` for your own file name.

```
# nmon -f -T -s 120 -c 360
```

You can produce the output using following link.

https://nmonvisualizer.github.io/nmonvisualizer/

Thanks